# Angular 14 Google Maps component responds with CORS error on requests

Tags: angular, google-maps, cors

We have an Angular web application that we recently upgraded to Angular 14. We are using the Google Maps "@angular/google-maps" package in version 14.2.7.
The maps component was working fine until recently, but now the map is not displayed anymore, instead we are getting 403 CORS error responses from the Maps API on the preflight requests from the maps component:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.maps.mapsjs.v1.MapsJsInternalService/GetViewportInfo' from origin 'https://<hostname>' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

The response is correct as the request does indeed not contain the required CORS header *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* when we inspect the request in the browser dev tools. That request is generated by the angular maps component, but we do not know a way to add this header to the request, or how to configure the request in any way.

This behavior only occurs when the app is deployed on the IIS webserver. If we start the map locally with ng serve, the map is displayed, although the request is exactly the same, but with a different origin ("localhost").

The maps code has been this way for a long time, so we do not think there is a problem there.

The maps code snippet:

```
<google-map [center]="center" [zoom]="zoom" width="100%" height="260px">
  <map-marker
    *ngFor="let building of buildings"
    [position]="{
      lat: building.Location.Latitude,
      lng: building.Location.Longitude
    }"
    [icon]="assets/marker.png"
  >
  </map-marker>
</google-map>
```

A copy to the request as curl:

```
curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/^$rpc/google.internal.maps.mapsjs.v1.MapsJsInternalService/GetViewportInfo" ^
  -X "OPTIONS" ^
  -H "authority: maps.googleapis.com" ^
  -H "accept: */*" ^
  -H "accept-language: en,en-US;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.7" ^
  -H "access-control-request-headers: access-control-allow-origin,request-context,request-id,traceparent" ^
  -H "access-control-request-method: OPTIONS" ^
  -H "origin: https:<hostnameremoved>" ^
  -H "referer: https:<hostnameremoved>" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-site: cross-site" ^
  -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.81" ^
  --compressed
```

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/animations": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/google-maps": "14.2.7",
    "@angular/localize": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "14.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.30.1",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^7.0.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^13.0.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^11.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.25.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.1",
    "devextreme": "22.1",
    "devextreme-angular": "22.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "log4ts": "^0.4.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^14.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.2.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.50.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "1.52.1",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-angular": "^3.0.3",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

We tried different minor and patch versions of the Angular 14 packages, but the behavior stays the same.
We did not change any settings on the IIS web server.

Comment: Since you are facing problem with deployed version, have you tried whitelist your domain or ip to the google service?

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6160020?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-a-trusted-domain-to-your-allowlist check this

Comment: Is this an authenticated request? If so, could it be the case you're not authenticating properly? Many APIs don't send proper CORS headers in the error case, so it might be sounding like a CORS issue but could actually be an authentication issue.